# How to define volume of Weyl transformation and diffeomorphism groups?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, diffeomorphism-invariance

I have a trouble in defining Weyl transformation and diffeomorphism group volumes in the formal expression of string partition function on some manifold $M$:
\begin{eqnarray}
Z_M=\frac{\int Dg [DX]_g}{V_\text{Weyl}\times V_\text{diff}}\exp(-S[X,g]).
\end{eqnarray}
For instance, how to define $V_\text{Weyl}$?
Formally,
\begin{eqnarray}
V_\text{Weyl}=\int D\xi,
\end{eqnarray}
where $D\xi$ is some Haar meassure associated to Weyl transformation.

We know that the meassure is required to respect general coordinate covariance, e.g.,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int[DX]_g\exp\left[-\int\sqrt{g}XX\right]\equiv1
\end{eqnarray}
defines the measure for the scalar field.

However, I don't have any idea on whether there is a similar constraint due to general covariance on the above $\int D\xi$?
A naive guess on the notation is that
\begin{eqnarray}
[D\xi]_{g^\xi},
\end{eqnarray}
where $g^\xi$ is the metric transformed by $\xi$ from an initial $g_{\mu\nu}$.
Even though this notation makes sense,
it potentially has the possibility that $V_\text{Weyl}$ can depend on the starting point $g_{\mu\nu}$, which is not we want.

Does someone know the exact definition?

Comment: A small comment: 1) there is a nice note by Weinberg from the 80s on these issues. 2) there is an ambiguity in normalization of the volume (you probably realise): this ambiguity should cancel between the numerator and denominator of your first equation.

Comment: 3) the usual convention for defining these path integrals (like your third equation) is to write $\int D\alpha \exp(\int \sqrt{g} ||\alpha||^2)=1$ where $||\alpha||^2$ is the norm more-or-less fixed by locality and coordinate invariance - insert the number of metric factors necessary to cancel all worldsheet indices. Articles by Polchinski and others (google `ultralocal metric') from the 80s discuss this, although I'm pretty sure it's also in his book. Another book which discusses this is by Nakahara.

Comment: @SvenForkbeard Many thanks for the comment and the hint. Now it is clear to me that the measure is defined through the tangent space at a fixed reference $g$, which is explained in Polchinski https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01210791 . 
Could you share the link to the Weinberg's note mentioned above?